# java illegalargumentexception(Android reverse Geocoder)

Tags: android, http-post, google-geocoder

My app is crashing after i call the method below and im sure i can get the latitude and longitude from my google map api and is it because of the googleurl???The error occur at    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); when i check the logcat.

```
public String  getAddressUrl(Context context) {
            String responseText = null;
             //String latitude = "38.89";
             //String longitude  = "-77.03";
            String googleurl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?";//url
            Log.v("TAG" , "Latitude is: " + mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude() + "Longitude is:" + mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
            StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sbuilder.append(googleurl);
            sbuilder.append("q = " + mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude() + "," + mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
            sbuilder.append("&output=responseText&sensor=true");
            String url = sbuilder.toString();

            Log.v("TAG", "url is: " + url);
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();
                InputStream is = httpentity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                responseText = sb.toString();
            }
            catch(ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseText;
        }
```

Logcat:

```
05-08 13:54:25.210: W/System.err(16238): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 33: http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q = 0.0,0.0&output = responseText&sensor = true
05-08 13:54:25.210: W/System.err(16238):    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at com.example.syndessales.CheckInDetails.getAddressUrl(CheckInDetails.java:96)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at com.example.syndessales.CheckInDetails.onMyLocationButtonClick(CheckInDetails.java:208)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$2.onMyLocationButtonClick(Unknown Source)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.m$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at euz.a(SourceFile:81)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at maps.e.bp.onClick(Unknown Source)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
05-08 13:54:25.230: W/System.err(16238):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Just Toast `mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude()` and `mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()` and check whether you are getting the correct values for Latitude and longitude

Comment: Yes i did just now and it gets the corrent latitude and longitude and i think the problem should related to the url as stated in googleurl variable and those append to it

Comment: since the logcat show the error there

Comment: Check if this works ..`String url =googleurl+"q = " + mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude() + "," + mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()+"&output=responseText&sensor=true"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try change the:

```
sbuilder.append(googleurl);
sbuilder.append("q = " + mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude() + "," + mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
sbuilder.append("&output=responseText&sensor=true");
String url = sbuilder.toString();
```

to:

```
    googleurl+="q="+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude()+","+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()+"&output=responseText&sensor=true&language=en-EN";
```

I've added the language param on the end, because sometimes google returned me the formatted addresses in other language :)
Or simply remove the spaces in "" brackets.
As I recall you shouldn't use spaces in the "" quotes if you want it to be an url. Also, you should encode this string to URL format. If you want to use normal spaces, then you should change them to %20 in the string.

Comment: I solve it using back the android stock geocoder and address class instead of google map api geocoder and i can only post the solution here after 8 hours because of low user reputation i think///